# Flex 4 : How to automatically resize the button based on content?

Tags: apache-flex

I would like to automatically resize my button (spark button) according it content (label text)?

Answer (score 0):

Anthony,

This should happen by default, if you don't explicitly define a width for the control.

Z

Answer (score 0):

The button is automatically resized once you addChild(...) your Button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution :-)

```
public class MyButton extends Button
{
    public function MyButton()
    {           
        super();            
    }               

    override protected function measure():void
    {
        super.measure();

        this.width = this.measuredWidth;            
    }                           
}
```

Now, my button is always correctly resize (width).

Thanks everybody

Anthony